# Created Promotion was not visible in Fredhopper Index server http://localhost:8180/preview/

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper, experience-optimization

I installed Experience Otimization Service in Fredhopper, in CMS Server and in Content Delivery Server. I can see the tab trageting in my CMS, where I created a promotion. When I access the URL **"http://localhost:8180/preview/"** from server I did'nt see my promotions created.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking in the Preview of the Business Manager, you would have to pick all of the right triggers for your Promotions to show up. That includes "SmartTarget Publication", "SmartTarget Region", and optionally "SmartTarget Page" (if you selected a specific Page in the '). Also add any custom triggers that you've selected.

If you've picked all the right triggers but still don't see your Promotions, it probably means that Fredhopper considers them invalid. If you don't see any warnings in the Targeting section, the most likely problem is that the Promotions are set to return content that isn't published to Fredhopper. So make sure the content you've set them to return is published to the right target and with the "Add to Experience Optimization" TBB in their Component Templates.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Smart Target Promotions created in the Promotions Dialog are not visible in the Fredhopper Business Manager.
You can show Smart Target Promotion in the Fredhopper Business Manager using following procedure:

1. Go to your Indexer Server FREDHOPPER_HOME\data\instances\indexer\config directory
2. In the config directory, create a file called smarttarget_api_extension.properties
3. Open smarttarget_api_extension.properties in a text editor and add: visible=true
4. Restart the Indexer instance
5. To hide the Promotions, set visible=false or delete the entire file and restart again